# Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, mysql, string, class, trim

```
public function Extragere_tabel()
{
    if($this->cuvant_cautat)
    {
        $cuvv=$this->cuvant_cautat;
        $this->cuvant_cautat = $this->bd->query("SELECT cuvant_stimul, cuvant_raspuns, aparitii FROM dc_asociatii WHERE cuvant_stimul='".$this->bd->real_escape_string(trim($this->cuvant_cautat))."' OR cuvant_raspuns='".$this->bd->real_escape_string(trim($this->cuvant_cautat))."' ORDER BY aparitii DESC");
        echo "<br /><center><table border=1 width=500>
        <tr><td><strong>Слово – стимул</strong></td><td><strong>Слово – реакция</strong></td><td><strong>Kоличество</strong></td></tr>";
        while($cuvintele = $this->cuvant_cautat->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
            {
                if($this->bd->real_escape_string(trim($this->cuvant_cautat)) == $cuvintele[0])
                    echo "<tr><td>$cuvintele[0]</td><td>$cuvintele[1]</td><td>$cuvintele[2]</td></tr>";
                elseif($this->bd->real_escape_string(trim($this->cuvant_cautat)) == $cuvintele[1])
                    echo "<tr><td>$cuvintele[1]</td><td>$cuvintele[0]</td><td>$cuvintele[2]</td></tr>";
            }
        echo "</table></center>";
    }
}
```

> Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\motor\classes\user.Class.php on line 94
>
> Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\motor\classes\user.Class.php on line 96

The line 94 is as below:

```
if($this->bd->real_escape_string(trim($this->cuvant_cautat)) == $cuvintele[0])
```

The line 96 is as below:

```
elseif($this->bd->real_escape_string(trim($this->cuvant_cautat)) == $cuvintele[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this:

```
public function Extragere_tabel()
{
    if($this->cuvant_cautat)
    {
        $cuvv=$this->cuvant_cautat;
        $this->cuvant_cautat = $this->bd->query("SELECT cuvant_stimul, cuvant_raspuns, aparitii FROM dc_asociatii WHERE cuvant_stimul='".$this->bd->real_escape_string(trim($this->cuvant_cautat))."' OR cuvant_raspuns='".$this->bd->real_escape_string(trim($this->cuvant_cautat))."' ORDER BY aparitii DESC");
        echo "<br /><center><table border=1 width=500>
        <tr><td><strong>Слово – стимул</strong></td><td><strong>Слово – реакция</strong></td><td><strong>Kоличество</strong></td></tr>";
        while($cuvintele = $this->cuvant_cautat->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
            {
                if($cuvv == $cuvintele[0])
                    echo "<tr><td>$cuvintele[0]</td><td>$cuvintele[1]</td><td>$cuvintele[2]</td></tr>";
                else if($cuvv == $cuvintele[1])
                    echo "<tr><td>$cuvintele[1]</td><td>$cuvintele[0]</td><td>$cuvintele[2]</td></tr>";
            }
        echo "</table></center>";
    }
}
```

Thank you!